# Dataframe shift by duration but round(/ceil) to the nearest time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a Dataframe with monotonic ts like:

```
ts   |   value1  |   value2
11          9            x
19         10            x
26          x            x 
29          x            x
32          x            x
```

for each `value1`, I want to find the `value2` at a timepoint just `x seconds` ago.

An example:

```
x seconds = 10

e.g. 1#
32 - 10 = 22, the ts just pass 22 is 26, then I want to find the value2 at ts 26,

e.g. 2:
29 - 10 = 19, then line2 ts is just 19, then I want to find the value2 at ts 29
```

so I wrote something like this:

```
x = 10
i1 = 0
row_num = df.shape[0]

for i in range(row_num):
    cur_row = df.iloc[i]
    cur_t = cur_row.ts
    cur_v = cur_row.value1

    delay_t = cur_t - x
    while i1 < row_num and df.iloc[i1].ts < delay_t:
        i1 += 1
    delay_v = df.iloc[i1].value2
    df.iloc[i,3] = cur_v - delay_v
```

It seems a complexity `O(n)`, but it is very slow. So I wanna know

1. why it's slow and how to improve it, a vectorize implementation is better
2. if you can solve the first question, can you improve it to find the `value2` closest to `ts - x` instead of just pass by?
   for example:

```
32 - 10 = 22, abs(22-19) =3, abs(22- 26)=4, then I want to find the value2 at ts 19,
```

that's much better

Comment: can you replace the `x` by real data and provide the exact expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact expected output is unclear, but you want a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
pd.merge_asof(df.eval('ts=ts+10')[['ts']], df, on='ts', direction='forward')
```

Output:

```
   ts  value1  value2
0  21    11.0     3.0  # value at ts=26
1  29    12.0     4.0  # value at ts=29
2  36     NaN     NaN
3  39     NaN     NaN
4  42     NaN     NaN
```

or, not exactly the same but the example here is ambiguous

```
pd.merge_asof(df[['ts']], df.eval('ts=ts-10'), on='ts', direction='forward')
```

Output:

```
   ts  value1  value2
0  11    11.0     3.0
1  19    12.0     4.0
2  26     NaN     NaN
3  29     NaN     NaN
4  32     NaN     NaN
```

Used input:

```
   ts  value1  value2
0  11       9       1
1  19      10       2
2  26      11       3
3  29      12       4
4  32      13       5
```

For the nearest value (not only forward):

```
pd.merge_asof(df.eval('ts=ts+10')[['ts']], df, on='ts', direction='nearest')
```

Output:

```
   ts  value1  value2
0  21      10       2
1  29      12       4
2  36      13       5
3  39      13       5
4  42      13       5
```

If you want all intermediates:

```
df[['ts']].join(
 pd.merge_asof(df.assign(ts_shift=df['ts']+10)[['ts_shift']],
               df[['ts', 'value2']].rename(columns={'ts': 'ts2'}),
               left_on='ts_shift', right_on='ts2', direction='nearest')
)
```

Output:

```
   ts  ts_shift  ts2  value2
0  11        21   19       2
1  19        29   29       4
2  26        36   32       5
3  29        39   32       5
4  32        42   32       5
```